# Connecting to websocket channels after successful connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, ws-client

I have been working on a websocket client application.

I am currently using the ws client library, because it is easy to add some headers (I need this for authentication purposes). I have made a successful connection to the server, but now I need to connect to a specific channel.

Current code:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

var option = {
  headers: {
    api_key: 'xxxxx'
  }
};

// I know this is not a correct url, but I removed it for security reasons
const url = '../websocket/'; 

const wss = new WebSocket(url, option);


wss.on('open', () => {

  console.log("Connection is succesfull");

  wss.on('message', message => {

    console.log(message);
  });

});
```

When I ran the code it prints the "Connection succesfull", but now I want to connect to a channel called /people. How can I do this.

I have tried several things like:

*Changed the url websocket/people.*

This doesn't work because it first needs to authenticate to user, before making a connection to a channel

*Changed the url to websocket/?people.*

I don't get an error, but I also don't get response back when something is send to this channel.

*Add this in the open function:*

```
 wss.on('/people', message => {

        console.log(message);
 });
```

I don't get an error, but I also don't get response back when something is send to this channel.

For the record. I only have access to the documentation and not to the server.

Comment: _"but now I need to connect to a specific channel"_. I don't think there's such a thing as a "channel" in the context of the `WebSocket` protocol, so it sounds like some sort of additional protocol that runs on top of `WebSocket`? Perhaps `socket.io`?

Comment: I don't know if you would call it a protocol, but the websocket server (in this case made with spring and stomp) has made several channels to subscribe to. Each channel gives different kind of information. Socket.io is an option, but it is a different library. It could be the case that I used a wrong library. Maybe better of using SockJS or socket.io or something else. I am still thinking my problem could be solved with the ws library

Comment: If you use `ws`, you have to implement the concept of "channels" yourself. There's nothing wrong with that, I'm just saying that `WebSocket` in and of itself doesn't have channels.

Comment: Thanks for the information. As far as I know there is not a way to create channels in `ws`. If I understand you correctly you'll need to create channels yourself or find a library that support is such as `socket.io`. In `socket.io` there are called rooms I think

Comment: Yes, that's correct.